# PHP echo's Resource ID instead of SELECT

Tags: php

I am trying to get a value out of a data base displayed. But all i get is a 'Resource ID #8'.

This is my code

```
$prijs_min = mysql_query('SELECT prijs FROM product ORDER BY prijs ASC LIMIT 1');
```

```
<td>
  <input type='text' name='prijs_limiet1' value='".$prijs_min[0]."' 
         id='prijs_limiet' />
```

The td tag is in an `echo`, so don't worry about that.

Comment: There's millions of php/mysql tutorials. http://phptherightway.com/#databases

Comment: I know. When I normally use this code, it works like a charm, but I tried alot to get it fixed, with no result...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mysql_fetch_assoc() or mysql_fetch_array() or mysql_fetch_object()

```
$prijs_min = mysql_query('SELECT prijs FROM product ORDER BY prijs ASC LIMIT 1');
$rs = mysql_fetch_array($prijs_min);
<input type='text' name='prijs_limiet1' value='".$rs['prijs']."' id='prijs_limiet' />
```

Hope this help.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_fetch_array()` or `mysql_fetch_object()`

```
result = mysql_query("select * from table");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo $row->yout_property;
}
```